# How does this code to find the longest common prefix work?

Tags: javascript

this function finds the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    // sort the array because it rearranges alphabetical order
   strs.sort();


  for (let i = 0; i < strs[0].length; i++) {
    if (strs[0][i] !== strs[strs.length - 1][i]){
return strs[0].substr(0, i);
    } 
  }



  return strs[0];  
};
```

I tried to understand this code but I can't !!!
how the first word of the array compared with the last word ... and what about the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code hides a significant chunk of it's logic in the unassuming `strs.sort()` call, which ensures that the first and last word in the resulting array contain enough information about the longest common prefix, that's why the remainder of the code only looks at the first (`strs[0]`) and last (`strs[strs.length-1]`) element of the newly sorted array.

It requires "turning the logic around" (IMO), but it's actually quite simple: if an array is sorted alphabetically, then you can guarantee that the longest common prefix of the first and the last word in the array is simultaneously the longest common prefix of the whole array (since by definition all values between the first and the last must have the same prefix, or they wouldn't have been sorted between them).

Additionally it loops over the *length* of the first entry, because by definition no common prefix can ever be longer than the first (or *any*) word in the array.

Then for each of those positions, if the first and last word differ at that position, it will return everything from the first word *up to, but excluding* that position.

If at the end of looping over every character in the first word we didn't find any characters that differ between the first and the last word, then we just return the first word as the longest common prefix.

One notable detail about this is how the "no common prefix" case is subtly hidden in plain sight: Imagine the input `["a", "b"]`:

- first it will sort that to `["a", "b"]`
- then it enter the loop once with `i` being `0`.
- then it will compare `"a"[0]` (i.e. the character `a`) to `"b"[0]` (i.e. the character `b`) and find that they are different. Therefore it will return `"a".substr(0, 0)`. `substr(0, 0)` called on any string will return the first 0 character, in other words: the empty string `""`.

Personally to make this code a bit more readable (and maybe understandable) I'd extract the first and last word into variables:

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
  strs.sort();

  var first=strs[0];
  var last=strs[strs.length - 1];

  for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    if (first[i] !== last[i]){
      return first.substr(0, i);
    }
  }
  return first;
}
```